# e.dataTransfer is undefined

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have a problem with my drag and drop item, when i drag got an error:
"e.dataTransfer is undefined"

drag function

```
dragstart: function(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('application/json', index);
    element.addClass('dragging');
}
```

Someone know where is the problem?

Answer (score 36):

Add `dataTransfer` prop explicitly:

```
e.dataTransfer = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
```

Comment: why was this not available by default?

Comment: I added this into my onDragStart function but it tells me that datatrasnfer is undefined: code...     onDragStart(event)
    {
        event.dataTransfer = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        console.log(event);
        event
            .dataTransfer
            .setData('text/plain', event.target.id);

        event
            .currentTarget
            .style
            .backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        console.log('hi');
    }

Answer (score 14):

In jquery you have to use it like this, it will work:

```
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
```